# Should I use "free" on 2D array when I used realloc?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free, realloc

I have 2D array declared like this:

```
int **array= NULL;
```

and then, somewhere in code I add elements like this:

```
int* tempArray1D = FuncThatReturnsIntStarArray();
array= (int**)realloc(array, (arraySize+ 1) * sizeof(int*));
*(array+size - 1) = tempArray1D;
```

If I want to delete one (last) element from 2D array, should I use free() and realloc on 1D array (int*) or realloac take care of all that.
For example:

```
free(*(array+ size- 1));
array= (int**)realloc(array, (size- 1) * sizeof(int*));
```

or just:

```
array= (int**)realloc(array, (size- 1) * sizeof(int*));
```

Example with free() cause some issues and im not sure if that way of avoiding memory leaks is correct and I have somewhere else in the code other bug, or it is just bad way of doing that.

Comment: If function `FuncThatReturnsIntStarArray` uses `malloc` or other dynamic allocation, then you probably have to use `free` if you no longer need the allocated memory. In general it is advisable to store the result of `realloc` in a temporary variable first and check the return code, e.g. `tmp = realloc(array, (size- 1) * sizeof(int*)); if(tmp == NULL) { /* handle error */ } else { array = tmp; }`

Comment: I recommend using the subscript operator `array[index]` instead of `*(array+index)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realloc()` has no knowledge about the things you store in the space. You need to take care of them yourself.

If `FuncThatReturnsIntStarArray()` allocates the memory whose address it returns, and if you have no other mechanism (like a function `FuncThatFreesAllocatedArray()`), you should free that memory.

*(BTW, `FuncThatReturnsIntStarArray()` is a bit misleading, because is does not return an array of `int` "stars" (vulgo: pointers). Something like `FuncThatReturnsPointerToInts()` is more appropriate.)*